Why sum of squares to calculate dispersion
The variance gives an idea of the dispersion of a distribution. To calculate the variance the sum of the difference of each value with the mean, each of these differences squared, is required. The differences are squared to avoid the use of negative numbers. But....why?  Absolute values of the differences would just do the job. By using the sum of squares larger numbers are given a disproportionate weight in the computation. As an example, if a difference between a value and the mean is 2, the square of the difference is 4, but if this difference is 3, is square is 9, so a difference of 1 is amplified to a difference in 5. Why is this done? Why not using absolute values?

A more general measure of variability is commonly referred to as the "spread" of a distribution. A "dispersion" is actually an even more precise value in the context of regression modeling.

Who said you can't use absolute values? Go for it. There's already quite a rich literature on such robust measures of spread.

We have many variations on this question here at CV. IMO, the main difference is that minimizing the squared error will elicit the expectation, whereas minimizing the absolute error will elicit the median. This makes a difference for asymmetric distributions.

Another almost identical existing question here.

There are two broad reasons why sum-of-squares is generally used for measuring dispersion instead of sum-of-absolutes:

The sum-of-squares quantities (e.g., sample variance, etc.) turn out to have "nice" statistical properties that are a bit simpler and more intuitive than the corresponding properties of the sum-of-absolutes.

Geometrically, sum-of-squares quantities are proportionate to distances between points in a vector space, which is a result of Pythagoras' theorem.  These quantities therefore correspond to intuitive relationships when you conceptualise data problems in geometric terms with datapoints represented as axes in Euclidean space.


